# How to create visualforce page with iframe with auto resizing height?

Tags: visualforce, iframe

I have a visualforce page with the following contents:

```
<apex:page controller="TheController" sidebar="false">
    <iframe src="{!url.url__c}" scrolling="true" id="iframe_id" width="100%" height="100%"/>
</apex:page>
```

and this is the result:
[image]

How can I get the iframe height to take up the full browser window's height? I want to use as much of the page as possible without having two scroll bars (1 for the content of the iframe, and one for the parent page).

**Update**:
When using styling as recommended in the stack overflow question in the comment below, I ended up with the following code and result:

```
<apex:page controller="AmbitionController" sidebar="false">
    <iframe src="{!url.url__c}" scrolling="true" id="ambition_iframe" style='position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; z-index:999'/>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Try style instead of attributes, a la:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109586/how-to-make-a-fullscreen-iframe-with-opaque-background

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not work. (unless I did something wrong)

Comment: There are lots of questions and answers about this on stackoverflow such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867985/iframe-auto-100-height but typically including various if/but qualifications. Some use JavaScript. So it will be interesting to see if you get an answer that works with how an apex:page is structured and in more or less all browsers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The trick is to resize the `iframe` with JavaScript after you know the size of the browser viewport:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false">
    <apex:iframe src="https://www.salesforce.com/" id="theFrame" />
    <script>document.getElementById('theFrame').height = window.innerHeight - 220;</script>
</apex:page>
```

Leave about 220 pixels for the Salesforce header and footer.

[image: iframe]

For bonus points, you can trim the container cell padding if you need and play with the 220 figure.

```
<style>table#bodyTable {border-collapse: collapse;} table#bodyTable td {padding: 0;}</style>
```

**Edit:** You can additionally deal with when the window is resized:

```
<script>
    (function() { //this wrapper prevents pollution of the global scope
        var windowOnresize = window.onresize;
        window.onresize = function() {
            if (windowOnresize) windowOnresize(); //don't trample the handler; intercept it
            document.getElementById('theFrame').height = window.innerHeight - 220;
        };
    }());
</script>
```

Comment: Do you know which browsers this works in (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10173236/window-innerheight-ie8-alternative)?

Comment: Nope. Keeping it short for the sake of example rather than importing a library @KeithC

Comment: it works in Chrome, and we only support Chrome, so I am happy. Thanks guys!

Comment: I've added your `onresize` handler @edgartheunready

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `angular JS`, here is something that you can leverage :

Write a height detecting directive for the app's body and update the iframe's height correspondingly.

```
angular.module('testApp').directive('elemHeight', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
                scope.$watch
      (
          function () {
              return elm[0].offsetHeight;
          },
          function (newValue, oldValue) {
              if (newValue != oldValue) {
                 //change iframe height here.
                  //}
              }
          }
      );
        }
    };
}]);
```